# PowerMockito is not working accordingly in my code, here is my code

Tags: spring-boot, powermockito

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Topic_Service.class)
class Topic_Service_test
{  
  private Topic_Service topic_service =  PowerMockito.spy(new Topic_Service());

  @Test
  void testing_test() throws Exception
  { 
   PowerMockito.spy(Topic_Service.class);
   PowerMockito.doReturn("hello").when(Topic_Service.class, "test_help");
   String s = topic_service.testing();
   Assertions.assertEquals("hello testing",s);
  }
}


@Service
public class Topic_Service
{
  public static String test_help()
  {
    return "test_help";
  }

 public String testing()
 {
   return test_help() + " " + "testing";
 }
}

POM.XML Dependencies

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version> 2.8.47</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

ERROR:-

```
 WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
 WARNING: Illegal reflective access by 
 org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.AccessibilityChanger 
 (file:/home/an.kumar1/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/mockito-core- 2.8.47.jar) 
 to field java.lang.Class.cachedConstructor
 WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of 
 org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.AccessibilityChanger
 WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access 
 operations
 WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release


    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
    Unfinished stubbing detected here:
    -> at 
    io.practice.practice_course_api.Topic_Service_test.testing_test(Topic_Service_test.java:73)

    E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
    Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
```

Hints:

1. missing thenReturn()
2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported.
3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before
   'thenReturn' instruction if  completed

Comment: If you want to use a mockito version of `2.8.9+` you are required to use PowerMockito `2.x`, check  [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito).

Comment: Please refrain from posting the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60846156/powermockito-is-not-able-to-mock-private-method) multiple times.